# How to make a block in the center of the screen?

Tags: html, css

How to make the **main-block** always in the center of the screen horizontally and vertically, even if you scaled down the window in the browser? Structure and adaptive design of code must be not edited.

Tried to do on the guide https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/, did not help.

```css
.title {
  margin: 10px auto 25px;
}

.block-row {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
  <h1 class="title">Title of this page</h1>
  <div class="block-row">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="block">
        some text in block
      </div>
      <div class="text-under">
        text there
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="block">
        some text in block
      </div>
      <div class="text-under">
        text there
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you past the full HTML code? If you want `.main-block` to always be centered (x and y) using Flex you need to word on its parent.

Comment: <body> <div class="main-block"> </div> </body>